# Why can't I use an arbitrary nesting of braces to construct most classes?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following code:

```
struct A;

struct B {
    B() {}
    B(A &&) {}
};

struct A {
    A() {}
    A(B &&) {}
};
```

Then I can use as many braces as I want to construct `A` or `B`.

```
// default construct A
auto a = A{};
// default construct B, forward to A
auto b = A{{}};
// default construct A, forward to B, forward to A
auto c = A{{{}}};
// etc.
auto d = A{{{{}}}};
auto e = A{{{{{}}}}};
```

Similarly, given

```
struct C {
    C(std::initializer_list<C>) {}
};
```

then I can also use as many braces as I want

```
// default construct C
auto f = C{};
// construct from initializer_list of one default constructed C
auto g = C{{}};
// construct from initializer_list of one C constructed from empty initializer_list
auto h = C{{{}}};
// etc.
auto i = C{{{{}}}};
auto j = C{{{{{}}}}};
```

Why doesn't the same argument work for a truly boring type?

```
struct D {
};
```

or, rewritten for clarity:

```
struct D {
    D() {}
    D(D &&) {}
};
```

This fails even on

```
auto k = D{{}};
```

Why does this not default construct a `D` with the innermost braces, and then pass that rvalue on to the move constructor of `D`?

See it live: https://godbolt.org/z/E763EPGh1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a special case that precludes `D{{}}`. It's a very particular set of conditions, so I imagine it's there specifically to prevent this exact recursion.

> **[over.best.ics]/4** However, if the target is
> (4.1) — the first parameter of a constructor
> ...
> and the constructor ... is a candidate by
> ...
> (4.5) — the second phase of **[over.match.list]** when the initializer list has exactly one element that is itself an initializer list, and the target is the first parameter of a constructor of class `X`, and the conversion is to `X` or reference to *cv* `X`,
> user-defined conversion sequences are not considered.

`D{{}}` is a list-initialization. `D(D&&)` constructor is considered by the second phase of it (the first phase looks at initializer-list constructors, like `C(std::initializer_list<C>)` in your second example). But for it to be viable, there needs to be an implicit conversion from `{}` to `D&&`, and **[over.best.ics]/4** suppresses it.